# Merging tags: 15 and 2013

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Although tag [15](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/15) has no wiki summary, I assume the questions are targeting Office/SharePoint 15, which is now publicly known as Office/SharePoint 2013.

Please, someone with enough privileges, make [15](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/15) a synonym for [2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2013).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have merged the tags as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this needs to be done, but don't have the privilege either. There is a proposed synonym already by John Chapman, proposing 15 as a synonym for 2010 **which is obviously wrong**.

Can any moderators rectify this?